# History doesn't update on url change using react-router-dom

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

So the problem was that when i tried to go back using browser native back, as well as `history.back(), history.push()` and `history.replace()` button it took me to the wrong path, so instead of going to the previous page i'd gotten into previous website, like completely different one.

To navigate through the pages i was using useHistory hook.

Answer (score 0):

So to do this you'd need to pass optional argument of state into the function call so that

```
history.replace('some-url')
```

will be changed to, for me at least

```
history.reaplce('some-url', '/')
```